# How to decode json strings to sync.Map instead of normal map in Go1.9?

Tags: json, go

I can decode json strings to a map with go language like this:

```
func main(){
  date := []byte(`{"127.1":{"host":"host1","list":["list123","list456"]},"127.2":{"host":"host2","list":["list223","list256"]}}`)
  var x interface{}
  json.Unmarshal(date, &x)
  t := x.(map[string]interface{})
  var aa []interface{}
  aa = (t["127.2"].(map[string]interface{})["list"])
  for _, v := range aa {
     fmt.Println(v.(string))
  }
}
```

but I wonder how to decode it to a sync.Map in Go1.9. I have tried many ways but failed, can anyone help me?

I tried like this:

```
    func main(){
      date := []byte(`{"127.1":{"host":"host1","list":["list123","list456"]},"127.2":{"host":"host2","list":["list223","list256"]}}`)
      var x interface{}
      json.Unmarshal(date, &x)
      t := x.((sync.Map)[string]interface{})  //compile error
}
```

Also I tried like this:

```
    func main(){
      date := []byte(`{"127.1":{"host":"host1","list":["list123","list456"]},"127.2":{"host":"host2","list":["list223","list256"]}}`)
      var x sync.Map
      json.Unmarshal(date, &x)
      fmt.Println(x) // but the map has nothing
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you really even want a [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map)? It has a very particular use case, and even documents that outside of its intended use case `"it will likely have comparable or worse performance and worse type safety than an ordinary map paired with a read-write mutex"`

Comment: I have a webserver to serve much clients, each client may use a goroutine to request the server and lookup the map on the server. Then the server response the result to each request . Also the server have one goroutine to update the map every 10 minutes  by requesting to a remote server. I will test the performance for each map type, thanks for your reminding.

Comment: sync.RWMutex seems absolutely reasonable for writes every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot directly unmarshal into a `sync.Map`, because `sync.Map` has no exported fields (so the Unmarshaler doesn't have any way to store data in it), and it doesn't implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface.

So you'll have to handle this yourself, probably by including a `sync.Map` in a type of your own, and implementing `json.Unmarshaler` on that type:

```
type Foo struct {
    sync.Map
}

func (f *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var tmpMap map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmpMap); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for key, value := range tmpMap {
        f.Store(key, value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In case you need a snippet to do it another way around

```
func (f Foo) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    tmpMap := make(map[YourTypeOfKey]YourTypeOfValue)
    f.Range(func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        tmpMap[k.(YourTypeOfKey)] = v.(YourTypeOfValue)
        return true
    })
    return json.Marshal(tmpMap)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to @jakub great answer about `MarshalJSON`, you can also have a generic function that doesn't check the type (since json doesn't care either)

```golang
func MarshalJSON(m *sync.Map) ([]byte, error) {
    tmpMap := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    m.Range(func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        tmpMap[k] = v
        return true
    })
    return json.Marshal(tmpMap)
}
```

This could take any kind of `sync.Map` and just Marshal it.

To add to the `UnMarshal` function from @Flimzy's answer, you can play a bit with the types by omitting the string part to make it more generics (pun intended, cry in corner):

```golang
func UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (*sync.Map, error) {
    var tmpMap map[interface{}]interface{}
    m := &sync.Map{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmpMap); err != nil {
        return m, err
    }

    for key, value := range tmpMap {
        m.Store(key, value)
    }
    return m, nil
}
```

In general it is good to play with the same Types when doing this sort of manipulation, because we are lazy and we don't want to rewrite functions ;)